# How can I return a vector?

Tags: clojure

I have a channel where I am putting values into inside a doseq loop.

This code reads from a list of isbns and for each isbn, does an amazon search to return contents of a book, and then calls another function to get the title and rank

```
(def book_channel (chan 10))
```

Comment: Are you closing book_channel anywhere?

Comment: Where would (close! book_channel) go? I'm confused on that.

Comment: You should close! the book_channel after you finish doseq

Comment: @rmcv I tried doing that and it didn't work. I updated my question and what I have right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some type of coordination to determine when all of your work is finished. You can pull that coordination out into the main thread fairly easily:

```
(def book_channel (chan 10))
(defn concurrency_test 
  [list_of_isbns]
  (doseq [isbn list_of_isbns]
    (go (>! book_channel 
            (get_title_and_rank_for_one_isbn
              (amazon_search isbn)))))
  (prn (loop [results []] 
               (if (= (count results) (count list_of_isbns))
                   results
                   (recur (conj results (<!! book_channel)))))))
```

Here, I used a loop that keeps waiting for results and adding them to the vector until we have as many results as we do isbns. You'll want to make sure that `get_title_and_rank_for_one_isbn` always generates a result that can be put on a channel, otherwise the loop will wait forever.

Comment: Can you do a little bit of explaining on what the loop portion does? Especially the count results part.

Comment: Edited the answer with a bit more explanation.

Comment: ohh. I see what it's doing. Very neat.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you use `clojure.core.async/into` rather than `clojure.core/into`. Here is an example of a round trip from collection to channel and back to collection:

```
user> (require '[clojure.core.async :as async :refer [<! <!! >!! >! chan go]])
nil

user> (def book-chan (async/to-chan [:book1 :book2 :book3]))
#'user/book-chan

user> (<!! (clojure.core.async/into [] book-chan))
[:book1 :book2 :book3]
```

`clojure.core.async/into` returns a channel that will have exactly one item written to it. That one item will be written once it's input channel closes. This keeps the whole thing asynchronous and it does require that the code putting things into the book-channel close the chan to signal that all the books are there.

Comment: well the error is gone now. But now I am printing out an empty vector

Comment: that almost always means the code that would be putting the result into the chan is throwing an exception. You are firing all the requests in parallel, which will throw rate limit exceptions once you get this in production and start running it on larger lists. It's good to do them in a small number of batches where each call in a batch is made after the previous call from that batch finishes. and put a delay between each call. If you are using emacs look in the buffer names *nrepl-server your-project-name* for the error (it's not in the default buffer list, you have to type the name)

Answer (score 1):

You should close! the book_channel after you finish pushing stuff into it.  Per async/into documentation - *"ch must close before into produces a result."*

```
(let [book> (chan)]
  (go
    (doseq [e (range 8)]
      (>! book> e))
    (close! book>))
  (<!! (async/into [] book>)))
```

Alternatively, you can use async/onto-chan which will close the channel for you:

```
(let [book> (chan)]
  (async/onto-chan book> (range 8))
  (<!! (async/into [] book>)))
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that there is only one go doing the entire job. I had go inside doseq so that multiple go's can handle a different ISBN

Comment: Number of "go" block doesn't matter, as long as you can tell when async/into can produce the final result.  If you use onto-chan, it will automatically close! the channel when all items are copied.  If you need "go" block to parallelise work in a coordinated way, you should consider adopting the pipeline functions.  See my other answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40615396/6013799)